# IIRF - Re-writing a URL without the query string

Tags: regex, iis-6, iirf

I have a URL that looks like this:

```
va_article.php?id=296&startRow=10#top
```

I still need to request the information in the query string, but I want it to display like this in the address bar:

```
va_article.php
```

I've done some straight 301 redirects and re-writes using IIRF with good results.  However, I haven't done much with the rewrite conditions.  Might I need some rewrite conditions for this to work and if so, which ones?

Thanks,

Comment: Rewrite the URL and put the query string in a header.

Answer (score 0):

Except if you're willing to hide the information elsewhere (cookie, which I wouldn't do!), this is **not possible**.

You will at least have to include that information into the url path somewhere, for example:

```
/296/10/va_article.php
```

Typically, you may do something like:

```
/articles/296/10
/articles/296?start=10
```

You'd need then 2 rules:

- One rule to *redirect* old urls to news urls
- One rule to *rewrite* new url to internal url

Similar to those two rules:

```
RedirectRule ^/va_article.php?id=(\d+)&startRow=(\d+)$ /articles/$1/$3 [I,R=302]
RewriteRule ^articles/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /va_article.php?id=$1&startRow=$2 [I,L]
```